# Get array from checkbox and then make a string in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a form on my website, that uses an array to submit checkbox data. I then try to manipulate that data with a foreach loop to add a ":" to each checkbox data, and then I want to make that into a single string I can insert into a database.

This is my HTML code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="pluginlist[]" value="'.$row['plugin'].'" /></td><td> '.$row['plugin'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

$row['plugin'] is data from a different table in the database.

This is my PHP code that $_POST the data, and then runs the foreach loop:

```
if(!empty($_POST['pluginlist'])) {
        foreach($_POST['pluginlist'] as $plugins) {
            $plugins1 = $plugins.":";
            }
            echo $plugins1;
}
```

The echo $plugins1 only echos the last checkbox data with a ":" on the end.

How can I make it so I can insert all the checkbox data into a database at once?

Comment: should be $plugins1 .= $plugins . ':";   in other words, you are not appending the previous string - missing .= . note you could use implode without a loop: $plugins1=implode(':',$_POST['pluginslist']);

Answer (score 3):

You can `serialize` the data, I find that much more convenient!

Or you can try

```
$plugins1 = implode(":" , $_POST['pluginlist']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate the values. Otherwise you're assigning a new value to `$plugins1` at each iteration.

```
$plugins1 .= $plugins.':'; // Correct - note the extra dot before the equal sign
```

And *not*:

```
$plugins1 = $plugins.':'; // Incorrect - would "reset" the value each time
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use `implode` to concatenate all array values to a single string:

```
$plugins1 = implode(':', $_POST['pluginlist'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do? I might not have understood your problem. The dot before the equals will concat but you might just want to implode.

```
$plugins1 = '';
if(!empty($_POST['pluginlist'])) {
        foreach($_POST['pluginlist'] as $plugins) {
            $plugins1 .= $plugins.":";
            }
echo $plugins1;
echo "<br />or<br/ >";
$plugins2 = implode ($_POST['pluginlist'], ':');
echo $plugins2;
```

Comment: Heh, I forgot they changed the arguments on implode... It should be glue and then array, but fortunately the function fixes this up for you. I guess the answer is answered before I could finish typing.